# Problemas en una clase generando un loop con iteradores en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando una clase para practicar iteradores en javascript. Este es mi codigo:

```
class iterador{
    constructor(...n){
    this.n = n
    this.lon = n.length
    this.indice = 0
    this.next = function next(){
        return this.indice < this.lon ? {value:this.n[this.indice++], done: false} : {done:true}
        }
    }
    loop(){
        let l = {}
        l[Symbol.iterator] = this.next
        console.log(l)
        let i = 0
        for(let value of l){
            console.log(value)
            i++
            if(i>this.lon) break
        }
    }
}
const ite = new iterador(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
ite.next().value // 1

ite.loop() // no funciona
```

la idea es que el metodo loop() me haga un recorrido por todo los parametros que envie al momento de crear el nuevo objeto ite, algun consejo?

Answer (score 0):

**Primera** solución, gastando tu iterator:

```
loop(){
  var item
  while (!(item = this.next()).done) console.log(item.value)
  console.log('done')
}
```

En tu example: `ite.loop()` will log 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 'done', como has llamado `ite.next()` ya una vez.

Lo que te falta es algo para reiniciar tu iterator lo si lo necesitas

**Segunda** solución, **sin mover tu indice** / gastar tu iterator:

```
loop(){
    this.n.forEach((item) => { console.log(item) })
}
```

En tu example: `ite.loop()` logs 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, y si llamas después `ite.next().value // 2`